# Internet Explorer cannot view my webpage the way it is supposed to.... Please help!

Tags: html, cross-browser

When I load my page in Safari and Firefox, even my ipod touch which is a variant of Safari it loads perfect.  When I use any version 6, 7, or 8 of internet explorer problems arise.  Basically, in IE 6 or 7 the banner ads look messed up, and the amazon code which is books go off the screen.  In IE 8 everything is fine except the books from amazon.  Every post with amazon books if there is more than 3 books in a post, it runs off the page and into the rest of the website, which looks terrible.  I can't figure out how to get it view like it does on Firefox or Safari.  If there isn't enough space, it should default to the next line but in IE it isn't.  Please advise what I can do to get my site to look right.

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of web development. Now begins your journey into the abyss of IE hacks and Opera hacked hacks. Sorry I hqave nothing of value to add at this moment.

Comment: What, you thought you could just write once, run everywhere? That's just ... adorable.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The guys here are pretty merciless if you a) haven't had a good go at sorting something out yourself, b) don't provide them with enough information to help you (and perhaps c) attempt to be light hearted). 
A better way to ask the question would be to word it something like "I'm having these isses (...) with this HTML (...). Could anyone tell me a good place to start reading up on browser compatibility issues?"

Answer (score 2):

One of the main issues with IE web dev is the [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) flag.  Anytime you have an element that looks broken in IE, try the following in that element's CSS:

```
.broken-element {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

The zoom property will trigger the hasLayout flag and often make IE render it properly.